# Deactivate forecast category value in Opportunity

Tags: opportunity, configuration, forecast

Salesforce throws error when deactivating a forecast category. I need to deactivate 'Commit' forecast category. Please refer below stage and forecast category mapping. I have mapped 'Commit' to 'Negotiation' stage (inactive).

[image]

Getting this error when attempt to deactivate.

> Cannot delete this value. This picklist must have at least one value
>   for status category "Commit".

I am trying to deactivate picklist value from forecast castegory piclist field.

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution to that problem?

Answer (score 1):

There are couple things to note here that are not obvious from the error message.

1) The Forecast Category picklist must have a forecast category value with a **Status Category** of "Commit" (not to be confused with the **Category Value** of "Commit".

2) Forecast Category Values can't currently be added, nor can any of the existing values' **Status Category** be changed. Forecast category values can only be edited. However, there's currently an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BpWfAAK) under review for Salesforce to implement this.

3) This means that the you can't actually deactivate the *Commit* picklist value, you can only edit the name so that there is still a picklist value with a **Status Category** of "Commit"

Comment: Thanks for your input Ayoola. I don't want add new values instead deactivate a value from Forecast Category picklist. I can see deactivate link available for that and added same in my question as well. If I cannot deactivate the value what's the purpose of that link?